# Symfony UseLocaleSubscriber and InMemoryUser

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-security, symfony-translator

I have `UserLocaleSubscriber` from Symfony documentation for switch locale by user. But my admin  user is stored "In memory", and the `InMemoryUser` class does not have the `getLocale()` method.

How may I run this subscriber only for user `User` entity. I tried `isGranted()` but couldn't get it to work.

```
class UserLocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if (null !== $user->getLocale()) {
            $this->session->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onInteractiveLogin',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only apply the locale change if the user instance is not of type `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\InMemoryUser` (if you are on Symfony 5.3), or `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User`  if you haven't gotten to that version yet.

Or better, check that the user entity you are getting is the one you expect. Let's say your user entity is `App\Entity\User`:

```php
public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
{
   $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

   if ( $user instanceof App\Entity\User && null !== $user->getLocale()) {
      $this->session->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
   }
}
```

Comment: This code is not function. I try this `if ($user instanceof UserInterface && null !== $user->getLocale()) {
            $this->session->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
        }` but this also is not function

Comment: What do you mean “it doesn’t function “? What error do you get? Are you importing the class? Your version wouldn’t work, since both classes implement `UserInterface`

Comment: Still same error `Attempted to call an undefined method named "getLocale" of class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User"`.

Comment: What version of Symfony are you on? Looks like you are on Symfony < 5.3

Comment: I am using Symfony 4.4 and the edited code run ok.